# How can i get the word by using character position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string which contain the text `JavaScript And PHP`. I get the position of `H` character that is `17`. I have get the character position of H but what i want now is to get the word which has H character at position `17`. Is this possible with java script/jQuery. If yes please help me to get the word in which there is a character at position `17`.

Comment: character and word are different , if you want something like that then take characters that starts from 17 till a blank space is came, or use regular expresions

Comment: @Arunprasanth KV It is possible from your comment i found out how it possible

Comment: @Hudixt Does that helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/d4tum8zy/

Comment: @Arunprasanth KV Nothing is impossible. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/56a7711y/ and my answer

Comment: @Hudixt  did't mean it is not possible, by a mistake i had write how it is possible, that's why i had edit the comment and remove the unwanted statement.

Comment: @Hudixt i just mean there is no inbuilt method for doing that , we want to apply our logic for that . Any way sorry for the term not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping Before and After can do this task. The code is used

```
<script>
var string = "JavaScript And PHP";
var k = string.substr(0,17);
        var n = k.split(" ");

    var se = n[n.length - 1];

var ke = string.substr(17,string.length);
var n = ke.split(" ");
var see = n[0];
alert(se+see);
</script>
```

JS FIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/56a7711y/

Answer (score 1):

loop through the characters before H until you arrive at a blank space then loop through starting from the character after the blank space (i.e the P in PHP) and go through that word until you arrive at a space :)

```
 var stringOld = "javascript and php";
var space = 0;
for(x=17; x>0; x--){
if(stringOld [x] === " ")
{
space = x;
    break;
}
}
for(y=space; y<stringOld.length; y++){
if((stringOld[y] === " ") ||( y=stringOld.length))
{
var newString = stringOld.slice(space,y);
 console.log(newString);
    //alert(newString);
}
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/edrcfq8a/1/

Comment: Not Working by the way +1 for your answer. I found the answer and posted it

Comment: yeah i havent tested, some variables ive entered wrong, trying to fix it in a jsfiddle now though. :)) congrats for sorting it yourself ;)

Comment: data comes two times in console  ""  , " php"

Comment: probably because i added a space at the end of the string by accident. delete that space but also add in the conditional > if(stringOld[y] === " " || y=stringOld.length-1) should work :)

Comment: edited the answer :)) considering I answered your question, would it be cheeky of me to ask to accept it ;)

Comment: its not. its because when you open the fiddle it automatically runs it. clear the console log and run it again. works perfectly

Comment: It wasn't working for me, i updated your fiddle and now its working http://jsfiddle.net/edrcfq8a/3/

Answer (score 0):

my idea

```js
$('#check').on('click',function(){

 var t = $('#text').val();
var a = t.split(' ');

var pos = Number($('#positions').val());
var cha = $('#char').val();

 $('#list').html(''); 
  
a.forEach(function(x){
  
  var $p = x.indexOf(cha,pos)

      if(x.indexOf(cha,pos-1) == pos-1){
        
             $('#list').append('<li>"' + x + '"  position of "' + cha +'" = ' + (x.indexOf(cha,pos-1) + 1) +'</li>');
        
      } 
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="100">I have a string which contain the text JavaScript And PHP. I get the position of H character that is 17. I have get the character position of H but what i want now is to get the word which has H character at position 17. Is this possible with java script/jQuery. If yes please help me to get the word in which there is a character at position 17.</textarea>

position : <input type="text" id="positions" value="5" /> <br/>

char : <input type="text" id="char" value="h" /> <br/>

<button id="check"> check word</button>

<ul id=list>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
```